# Apache Simple Configuration Issue: Setting up per-user directory permission denied problem

Tags: apache-2.2

I am just getting Apache 2.2 running on Fedora 13 Beta 64-bit.  I am running into issues setting my per-user directory.  The goal is to make localhost/~user map to /home/~user/public_html.  I think that I have the permissions right because I have 755 to /home/~user, and I have 755 to /home/~user/public_html/ and I have 777 for all contents inside of /home/~user/public_html/ recursively set.

My mod_userdir configuration looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#
# UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
# of a username on the system (depending on home directory
# permissions).
#
UserDir disabled root
UserDir enabled huckphin

#
# To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
# directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
# the following line instead:
#
UserDir public_html
```

The error that I am seeing in the error log is this:

```
[Sat May 15 09:54:29 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~huckphin/index.html denied
```

When I login as the apache user, I know that /~huckphin does not exist, and this is not what I want.  I want it to be accessing ~huckphin, not /~huckphin.  What do I need to change on my configuration for this to work?

[Added after comments]

Hi Andol, thank you for your suggestions.  So, first off, you said that you assume that I have the userdir module enabled, but I am not sure what that means exactly.  That could be part of the problem.

I do have the Module loaded, using the LoadModule directive.  I have this:

```
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
```

I also did a find on where mod_userdir is, and I found it located here:

```
[huckphin@crhyner-workbox]/% find / . -name '*mod_userdir.so*' 2> /dev/null
/usr/lib64/lighttpd/mod_userdir.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_userdir.so
```

Is there something else I need to enable?

Also, my directory configuration was mentioned.  I have uncommented the default configuration given.  I have not looked into what all of the configurations mean, and this could probably explain the issue.  Here is the Directory that I have for the user directories:

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when Apache refers to /~foo/ in its log files, it is talking about the url, and not the file system path. In other words, there's nothing suggesting that it's looking at the wrong place.

I assume you also have the userdir module enabled, not just the configuration? What about the Directory configuration for /home/*/public_html? Also, what about the file system permissions for /home?

Comment: make sure the user's directory can be traversed by apache. it needs full read permissions to `/home/user/public_html` i.e. `chmod 755 /home/user/public_html` and execute permissions on `/home/user/`, i.e. `chmod 711 /home/user` if i recall correctly, 711 is the minimum.

Comment: Hi cpbills, thanks for the suggestion.

I have logged in as the apache user using root, and I am able to traverse the /home/user/public_html directory, so I believe that I have set the permissions correctly.  I do have /home/user set to 755, and /home/user/public_html set to 755, and everything under /home/user/public_html/* to 777, so I think that my permissions are set.

Comment: Hi andol.  I have added my settings for <Directory>.  Also, my permissions for home is set to 755.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little upset.  I found the answer, but it was just a guess.  Sure enough, nothing about my configuration was incorrect.  I stopped SELinux by going to System -> Administration -> SELinux Management (I am using GNOME for my window manager, btw), and shutdown SELinux, and I was able to view my user directory webpage.

So, I have found out that SELinux was causing the problem.  I am not sure if I want to go through and enforce a policy specifically for SELinux.  I think that might be another thread, but I have found the problem!

Thank you for the help, though.  It made me think in a different direction, which helped me come to this conclusion!  I appreciate the help!